# Use a Microsoft account in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that needs to work with outlook to do things such as read and forward emails.
Is there any way to easily log in to Microsoft through chrome extensions so that I can call the APIs?

I've tried a few things, like a separate website to log in, but it seems far too complex for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to create an Azure app. There is a guide online. Try and make the calling script first, then implement it. Since it needs a redirect uri you may need to investigate how Chrome identity works.